# junit TestWatcher doesn't seem to realise that tests have run

Tags: java, junit

The code below is modified(barely) from http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html 
I would expect to see a pass and fail like from within the @rule to be printed to console when the test is executed, instead I see nothing. This leads me to believe I'm not understanding how this is supposed to work. If someone can explain why this doesn't work as I expect it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class SimpleWatcher {
    private static String watchedLog;

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watchman= new TestWatcher() {
            @Override
            protected void failed(Throwable t, Description d) {
                    watchedLog+= d + "\n";
                    System.out.println("Failed");
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded(Description d) {
                    watchedLog+= d + " " + "success!\n";
                    System.out.println("Pass");
            }
    };

    @Test
    public void fails() {
            fail();
    }

    @Test
    public void succeeds() {
    }
 }
```

Comment: That code works for me - it prints `Failed` and `Succeeded`. Are you sure you are running in a context that includes junit-4.9.jar?

Comment: I just thought of that. Checking my jar now :/

Comment: That was the problem! Old jar file. Thanks :)